# Deserializing XML in Object using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<ArrayOfString>
    <stringValues>
        <stringvalue>teste1</stringvalue>
        <stringList> 
             <stringText>stringList1</stringText>                                   
        </stringList>
    </stringValues>
</ArrayOfString>
```

My contract is as following:

```
[KnownType(typeof(StringList))]
[DataContract(Name = "stringValues", Namespace = "")]
public class StringValues
{

    [DataMember(Name="stringvalue",Order=1)]
    public string stringvalue { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="stringList",Order=2)]
    public StringList stringList { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "stringText")]
public class StringList : List<string>
{

}
```

And the code used to deserialize is:

```
var testexml = @"<ArrayOfString>
                            <stringValues>
                                <stringvalue>teste1</stringvalue>
                                <stringList> 
                                    <stringText>stringList1</stringText>                                   
                                </stringList>
                            </stringValues>
                         </ArrayOfString>";

        XmlDictionaryReader stringsReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateDictionaryReader(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(testexml)));
        DataContractSerializer ArrayOfString = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<StringValues>), "ArrayOfString", "");
        var strings = ArrayOfString.ReadObject(stringsReader);
```

When i run it the stringList property should have one item, but instead it has zero items. 
I belive, there is something wrong in my contract. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to debug deserialization problems like this is to create an in-memory example of your class, then serialize it out to a string and compare what you got with what you want to deserialize.  If there are differences, then that's your bug.

Here's code that shows how to create sample serialized XML for a class:

```
    private static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
    {
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
    }

    private static string GetXml<T>(T obj, DataContractSerializer serializer) where T : class 
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.IndentChars = "    "; // The indentation used in the test string.
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, obj);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(T obj) where T : class
    {
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        return GetXml(obj, serializer);
    }
```

Note - not a complete answer to your question but the code might be useful and is too long for a comment.

**Update**

OK, I tried that myself.  You need to set the namespace on the DataContract of the upper class to be the same as the namespace as the nested class, and the same as is given in the XML file itself:

```
[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "stringText", Namespace="")]
public class StringList : List<string>
{

}
```

If you don't, `DataContractSerializer` will assume that they are in different namespaces, and expect something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfstringValues xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <stringValues>
        <stringvalue>teste1</stringvalue>
        <stringList xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Clr.Namespace">
            <d3p1:stringText>stringList1</d3p1:stringText>
        </stringList>
    </stringValues>
</ArrayOfstringValues>
```

Where `Clr.Namespace` is the CLR namespace in which you defined your classes.  (Yes, apparently `DataContractSerializer` [assigns a default namespace based on the c# namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in the absence of any directive telling it otherwise.)

You can also use the [`ContractNamespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.Serialization.ContractNamespaceAttribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute on your entire module or assembly if you don't want to have to do this repeatedly.